# How can I have some checkboxes prechecked in a list of checkboxes with AngularJS and Firebase ?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am making a mobile app with ionic and firebase and thus i am using AngularFire. I want to display the list of all the users below a search bar for my user to find new friends. When the user finds a friend, he can click on the checkbox beside it and it adds it in his database. 
My firebase structure looks like this :

```
users
frankid : 
   name : frank
   friends :
          Lisaid : true
Lisaid :
   name : Lisa
   friends : 
           frankid : true
```

I have managed to display the list of all the users with the code below 
in HTML :

```
        <form class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" ng-model ="query" placeholder="Rechercher un ami">
        </label>
    </form>
        <ion-list>
                <ion-checkbox class="item item-checkbox-right"  ng-click="addFriend(user.$id)" ng-repeat="user in users | filter : query ">{{user.name}}</ion-checkbox>
        </ion-list>
```

in JS :

```
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(reference.userRef());
```

I can retrieve the list of the user's friends id with the code :

```
    //dataSnaphot.key() va contenir la liste des users id amis de notre utilisateur 
userRef.child('friends').on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot){
    reference.userRef().child(dataSnapshot.key()).once("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    //It displays the list of the user's friend id
    console.log(dataSnapshot.key());
    var usersfriends = dataSnapshot.key();
    });
});
```

When my user browses the list of users, I want my user's friends to be already checked. I don't know how to do it.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: In your controller, once the data is returned, simply change the check boxes you want to be enabled to have the proper value.

Comment: Your code isn't creating a list of checkboxes based on friends, it's simply iterating the list of users. It's impossible to tell what you're trying to achieve here (checked relative to what? If the currently being iterated user has its own uid in the friends list?). Also, your ion-checkbox has no ngModel. So it's unclear how it could mark anything as checked. Docs on ion-checkbox are [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/). If you give it a shot and still have issues, add your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.